# How can I disable the "convert to freeform linguistic input" dialog box?

Tags: free-form-input, user-interface

So I'm putting in some function, busy typing away.  Then after I've entered some text, I pause for a few seconds.  In this time, the notebook pops up the question "Convert to Free-Form Linguistic Input," like this:

[image]

It is already highlighted such that if I hit Enter it will go ahead and do this conversion, deleting a large chunk of what I've already typed and replacing it with something useless. (edit to add:  This cannot be undone through the Undo menu option!!!)

Now I love some of the interface improvements to the newer versions of Mathematica.  Specifically, I love how it will bring up a list of pre-defined functions and variables while I'm typing. That has saved me much time.  But I can't ever see a situation where I would want to use free-form linguistic input.  I'm not sure exactly what it is, but I know I don't want it.  How can I disable this?  I already disabled the "Suggestion Bar".

I'm using version 10.0 on Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely you want to disable the "Enable natural language detection". This is in the same list in the preferences as the "Suggestion Bar" setting.

Comment: @JasonB No problem. You also could try to write more cryptic function names like `f3q904m[x$001a_]:=...` to prevent that Mathematica believes it could help you with *natural language* :-)

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to do this? Like `SetOption[...]`